# (Almost) no credit unions in New York City, why?

Tags: credit-unions, new-york

After relocating from the West Coast to New York City, I was surprised to find major banks on every street corner, but only very few credit unions. And of the few ones, many aren't even open to the general public - such as the "New York Times Employees Federal Credit Union", the  "Actors Federal Credit Union" and so on.

I've had very positive experiences with credit unions and would like to continue doing business with them. Any insight into what's going on here? Did the big banks chase (no pun intended) the CUs away from their home territory? Can anyone recommend a good CU in the general NYC area?

Comment: I have found that a credit union with a good online experience works for me.  (However, I admit to having several banks, and always one with a local branch in case I need to go in.  It is a rare occurrence, but once a year is worth keeping a local branch option.)

Comment: Why?  because NYC is the hq for the banking industry, which hates and actively tries to kill credit unions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 credit unions in the Metro NY area that are open to everyone:

- Montauk CU, 111 W. 26th St, NYC
- Melrose CU, 13930 Queens Blvd, Briarwood.

You might also want to check out [aSmarterChoice.org](http://www.asmarterchoice.org/) to see if there are other credit union options based on where you live, work, worship & more.

Answer (score 4):

I would have been tempted to dismiss your claim, but [the data I found shows that you're correct](http://www.creditunions.com/articles/the-power-of-data-credit-union-deposit-market-share-growth/).

On the plus side, the growth rate in credit union market share is higher in New York than it is in California.

While there is no question that bankers hate credit unions, I can't tell you why credit unions have a smaller market share in NY. Maybe the regulatory environment is part of it. Banks have a big lobby, and they pay a lot of taxes in NYC.